# Android User-interface with regards to fragments; best way to update?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

So I have several fragments connected to a viewpager that is just on the generic android set up that comes with Eclipse.

I was wondering; when it comes to updating element views for things like progress bars or textviews; should I update those elements inside of the fragment's .java file or should I update them from some sort of centralized UI controller object?

The way I have it set up now is a controller object with several async tasks inside of it for each fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the updation of views inside fragment based applications requires `activity to fragment, fragment to fragment communication`. So for this you need the `event based mechanism` so that the  your target view/controller get to know that something has happened like say download is complete so hide the progressbar.

So I googled regarding this. I found one libray [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) eventbus. Which helped me in such communications. Hope you get the idea and this will help you as well.